# How to filter data for next week in dax?

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas, ssas-tabular

I have a full DimDate dimension with all columns, and I try to filter data for ‘next week’.

I have tried:

```
'Date'[Week Year Week Number] = CONVERT(CONCATENATE( YEAR(TODAY()  ),WEEKNUM(TODAY(),21)    ),INTEGER)+1
```

But of course I have 2 problems:

- when week is 52, I will just get 53.
- Also the column  Week Year Week Number   has values like 202202 And my WEEKNUM concat returns something like 20222 (they are different!)

How can I appropriately filter for ‘next week’ data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add days to TODAY with simple arithmetic: `TODAY()+7`. Then you can convert the year and weeknum without special logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a calendar table where the weeknums are continuous like this which would help in filtering for next week

```
Calendar=
VAR _cal1 =
    CALENDAR ( DATE ( 2010, 1, 1 ), DATE ( 2020, 1, 1 ) )
VAR _cal2 =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        _cal1,
        "weekNum",
            VAR _minDate =  --- what is the min date in this calendar table
                MINX ( _cal1, [Date] )
            VAR _x =
                WEEKDAY ( _minDate, 1 ) - 1
            VAR _y = _minDate - _x
            VAR _z =
                CEILING ( DIVIDE ( ( [Date] - _y ), 7 ), 1 ) ---[Date] - _y gives the last Sunday before the minDate in the calendar
            RETURN                                           ---from when the WEEKNUM starts
                _z
    )
RETURN
    _cal2
```